# Null assignment from screen flow picklist field to auraenabled field

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, screen-flow

Im trying to assign some fields to an apex class (this apex class has those variables with the @AuraEnabled tag). The problem is that I have one field which is a picklist field and is always assigning null value.

Picklist Field:

[image: Picklist Field]

Flow:

[image: Flow]

GetRecord:

[image: GetOppRT]

Result from debug:

[image: Result]

Apex-Defined variable:

[image: Variable]

This is my apex class:

```
public with sharing class OpportunityFieldsByCSV {

    @AuraEnabled
    public String oppName;

    @AuraEnabled
    public String oppRT;

    @AuraEnabled
    public Date oppCloseDate;

    @AuraEnabled
    public Id oppCampaign;

    public OpportunityFieldsByCSV (String oppName, String oppRT, Date oppCloseDate, String oppCampaign) {
        this.oppName = oppName;
        this.oppRT = oppRT;
        this.oppCloseDate = oppCloseDate;
        this.oppCampaign = oppCampaign;
    }

    public OpportunityFieldsByCSV() {}
}
```

Thanks in advance!